# Popen a command that contains need to say yes for all outputs

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

I need to automate the following command

```
cmd="yes | vgremove <vgname>"
```

whenever I code this command with

```
Popen(cmd.split(),stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
```

it does not complete. I suspect it waits till the command gets complete, so the pipe is struck, is there an alternative for this???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a much easier way in this case:

```
Popen('vgremove -f <vgname>')
```

As for your question specifically:

```
p = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write('yes')
```

Answer (score 3):

Piping is a shell feature, so you'll need `shell=True` on that. What you're doing without `shell=True` is executing `yes` with arguments. `yes` never stops executing so the subprocess never returns.